# How to make South works in Heroku for a Django app

Tags: python, database, django, heroku, django-south

I am working on Python/Django and I am trying to use South to manage my database. In local environment is working great. The problem comes when I deploy to Heroku. The issue is that when I create a migration with

```
$heroku run manage.py schemamigration mydjangoapp
```

It looks like it works (the shell confirmed it), however, then I try to use migrations and it won't work. When I do:

```
$heroku run python manage.py migrate mydjangoapp
```

I get this;

```
The app 'createtuto' does not appear to use migrations
```

I checked on the problem and it looks like heroku doesn't allow South to create the migration directory at /myDjangoapp/migrations.

Is there anything I can do to make it work?

I tried to use convert_to_south, but I got the same results: At the beginning it looks like it worked, but It did not, not migration created.

Comment: Why are you trying to create migrations on Heroku? Heroku should simply be your production environment where you use pristine code. All of this stuff should be done in your local development enviroment.

Comment: @ChrisPratt What are you talking about? How do you expect your production application to evolve over time?

Comment: @HorseloverFat: You never run migrations against production. You migrate schema locally. Test the changes. Then generate or write SQL to make those changes in production, preferably with the assist of a DBA, if your organization has one. If you're doing everything yourself, it's still better to apply SQL, rather than blindly migrate, because then you can double-check the exact changes that are going to be applied to your database before making those changes.

Comment: @ChrisPratt you may be right, but that's only likely to happen for a) sites with small databases, b) sites with huge budgets, or c) sites with custom (non-ORM-generated) tables. The point of any tool such as this is to give a developer or two a lot of power; that does have risk, as one must trust the tool, but it doesn't make asking the question a ridiculous one.

Answer (score 10):

When you run 'heroku run' it connects to an isolated instance of your deployed environment. It does create the migration, however that migration is not contained within your slug. Each time you do a 'git push heroku master' it installs your dependencies and packages your application into a slug. This is more or less a tarball of your application which enables Heroku to easily deploy it to new dynos as you scale up.

In order to run a migration on Heroku you would create the migration locally, check it in, then run the migration on heroku. Something similar to:

```
manage.py schemamigration mydjangoapp
git add mydjangoapp/migrations/*
git commit -m 'adding new migrations'
git push heroku master
heroku run python manage.py migrate mydjangoapp
```

Comment: Nop it didn't work. When I try what you suggested I got this:

Comment: ! Error found during real run of migration! Aborting.
--------------
 ! Since you have a database that does not support running
 ! schema-altering statements in transactions, we have had 
 ! to leave it in an interim state between migrations.
-------------------------

Comment: For now the only option I have is to back-up the DB and do "manage.py reset myapp" and then "syncdb" again and recover from the back-up.

Answer (score 5):

I follow the direction from Mike Ball here successfully:
http://www.mikeball.us/blog/using-south-on-heroku/

Like CraigKerstiens answer said, you should make the migration locally first then push to heroku. Before you make a migration on Heroku, make sure you convert your Heroku instance into south, for example

```
heroku run bin/python django_project/manage.py convert_to_south django_app
```

Comment: I'll just add to this (as there's no way to comment on the blog you linked to) that I had to do a fake migration first, both locally and on Heroku.